IIS - terminate connections on server-level exceptions
I'm working on some Security Technical Instruction Guides (STIGs) and I have a new rule with the following discussion text:

The web server defines a set of exceptions for every HTTP status code. Each exception class has a status code according to RFC 2068: Codes with 100-300 are not really errors; 400s are client errors, and 500s are server errors. If not directly specified, headers will be added to the default response headers.
In the event of an anomaly or exception during the processing of requests, it is safer to terminate the connection to prevent malformed requests from exploiting potential protocol vulnerabilities.

The check text is:

Verify the web server terminates the connection if server-level exceptions are triggered when handling requests.
If the web server does not terminate the connection if server-level exceptions are triggered when handling requests, this is a finding.

My question is how do you do this in IIS or is this even possible?
We have our server configured so that if a server-level exception occurs, a custom exception page is displayed.  My understanding is that if this is the case, additional response headers as mentioned in the discussion would not be added to the response.
Is this the best way to handle this?

Why am I being downvoted for asking a question?


My question is how do you do this in IIS or is this even possible?


Create code that does something simple like click a button to display a friendly message.

Instead of displaying the message, throw an exception instead.

Confirm that the friendly message was not displayed. (The session was terminated due to the exception).


